# how to Change element of html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 767){
    $("#second").insertBefore("#first"); }
    else{
        $("#first").insertBefore("#second"); }
     });
});
</script>
```

I want to change the html element. In the above code nothing is wrong but when our screen size has already small (< 767) it will not work due to resize() function and when we remove resize function then it will work but it failure when we increase the screen size. It can't change the element.
Actually i am looking a solution like @media css property. We all Know when we use media we can see the effect through inspector. I got a code but it will not working

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent += "@media screen and (max-width:767px) {"+
$("#second").insertBefore("#first");+" }";
```

Actually the code was not same. I edited and try to run but not working.
How to change elements like in small screen with media query? or any other solution but must be responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to swap html elements according to screen width? If so, why not use CSS?

```
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #first-copy, #second-copy {
    display: block;
  }

  #first, #second {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<html>
<div id="first" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100px; text-align: center">
  <p>
    first element
  </p>
</div>
<div id="second" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100px; text-align: center">
  <p>
    second element
  </p>
</div>
<div id="second-copy" class="hidden" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100px; text-align: center">
  <p>
    second element
  </p>
</div>
<div id="first-copy" class="hidden" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100px; text-align: center">
  <p>
    first element
  </p>
</div>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8sug5pws/2/

Comment: This is also an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
         change();
     });
     change();
});
function change(){
    if($(window).width() < 767){
        $("#second").insertBefore("#first"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#first").insertBefore("#second"); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.trigger(resize);`

Comment: can you tell more about that?  I found the info related to .trigger from http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ i understood but still i have no idea how to use resize with .trigger.

Answer (score 0):

U can use @media screen 
for example:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #info {
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

In CSS Of course

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code its working fine...

    resize_solution();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resize_solution();
        }); 
    });
    function resize_solution(){
        if($(window).width() < 767){
            $("#second").insertBefore("#first"); 
        }
        else{
            $("#first").insertBefore("#second"); }
    }
```